# jQuery Mobile Dual Range slider

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I made a dual range slider in JQM by placing slider on top of each other. Is there a way we can stop min exceeding max value?

I'm not sure slider is using HTML5 range input type

```
<style type="text/css">
            .priceRangeInfo{
                position: relative;
                height: 30px;
                margin-top: 60px;
            }
            .priceRangeInfo label{
                position: absolute;
                top: -30px;
                left: 10px;
            }                            /* moves label field */
            .priceRangeInfo #buying_slider_min{
                top: -40px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 100px;
            }       /* moves first input field */ 
            .priceRangeInfo #buying_slider_max{
                top: -40px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 170px;
            }      /* move second input field */ 
            .priceRangeInfo div.ui-slider{
                position: absolute;
            }                   /* move both sliders - adressing 1st slider with CSS is hard */ 
            .priceRangeInfo div:last-child{
                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
            }                 /* correct 2nd slider position to fit exactly on top of 1st slider */
        </style>
        <div class="priceRangeInfo">
              <label for="buying_slider_min">Price</label>
              <input type="range" name="buying_slider_min" id="buying_slider_min" class="minBuyingSlider" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
              <input type="range" name="buying_slider_max" id="buying_slider_max" class="maxBuyingSlider" value="100" min="0" max="100" />
        </div>
```

Just found YUI has a great dual slider that works perfectly with JQM!!!

```
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/slider/slider_dual_with_highlight.html
```

Comment: Please edit your question with some example code you have tried and/or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: sorry but cannot put in jsfiddle as they need to contain some images. I have posted some code above

Comment: YUI dual slider you cited doesn't seem to work on my Android phone.  Not sure this is a viable option for anyone working in mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work:

- http://jsfiddle.net/NkjQr/2/
- http://jsfiddle.net/NkjQr/3/ (Still a little buggy)

JS

```
$('#buying_slider_min').change(function() {
    var min = $(this).val();
    var max = $('#buying_slider_max').val();

    if(min > max) {
        $('#buying_slider_max').val(min);
      $('.maxBuyingSlider').slider('refresh');  
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="priceRangeInfo">
      <label for="buying_slider_min">Price</label>
      <input type="range" name="buying_slider_min" id="buying_slider_min" class="minBuyingSlider" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
      <input type="range" name="buying_slider_max" id="buying_slider_max" class="maxBuyingSlider" value="100" min="0" max="100" data-track-theme="b"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.priceRangeInfo{
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.priceRangeInfo label{
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: 10px;
}                            /* moves label field */
.priceRangeInfo #buying_slider_min{
    top: -40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}       /* moves first input field */ 
.priceRangeInfo #buying_slider_max{
    top: -40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
}      /* move second input field */ 
.priceRangeInfo div.ui-slider{
    position: absolute;
}                   /* move both sliders - adressing 1st slider with CSS is hard */ 
.priceRangeInfo div:last-child{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but is there a way we can get it not buggy? I tried jQuery UI and others on JQM but nothing works as JQM itself uses slider() as function for javascript. Is there a way we can prevent pointer to go over min or max each other?

Answer (score 0):

you must create the slider so:
html:

```
 <div id="slider-container-zucker" class="slider_style"></div>
```

and js:

```
 $(function () {

$('#slider-container-zucker').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 9,
    values: 0, 9,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#Result").html(result);
            }
        });            

    }
});
```

});

if something is not clear you can ask me