# How can I make a range slider in jQuerymobile?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to make a slider in jQuerymobile with two selection points, and a highlight inbetween?
I'm looking for something like this:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range but for a mobile framework.

Answer (score 1):

At the [moment](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/2401) there doesn't seem to be a built in way to do so, however you might want to have a look at this SO question
[jQuery Mobile Dual Range slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895748/jquery-mobile-dual-range-slider)